# Converting NSMutableDictionary to JSON with NSJSONSerialization returns different results

Tags: iphone, ios, json, nsmutabledictionary, nsjsonserialization

When I try to convert `NSMutableDictionary` to JSON with `NSJSONSerialization` it returns different results:

Code:

```
-(NSString*)JSONRepresentation{

    return [self JSONRepresentation:NO];
}

-(NSString*)JSONRepresentation:(BOOL)whiteSpaces{

    NSError* error = nil;
    NSData * result = nil;

    if(whiteSpaces)
        result = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    else
        result = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    if (error != nil){
        NSLog(@"Error:%@",error);
        return nil;
    }

    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[result bytes]];
}
```

This is how I use it:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setObject:@"xxx" forKey:@"experiment"];

NSLog(@"(%@)", [dict JSONRepresentation]);
```

Results in consecutive tries:

```
2013-08-01 12:31:45.066 Hercules Demo[8763:c07] ((null))
2013-08-01 12:31:49.988 Hercules Demo[8763:c07] ((null))
2013-08-01 12:31:52.838 Hercules Demo[8763:c07] ({"experiment":"xxx"})
2013-08-01 12:31:59.432 Hercules Demo[8763:c07] ({"experiment":"xxx"})
2013-08-01 12:32:03.160 Hercules Demo[8763:c07] ((null))
2013-08-01 12:32:06.232 Hercules Demo[8763:c07] ({"experiment":"xxx"})
2013-08-01 12:32:08.395 Hercules Demo[8763:c07] ((null))
```

Comment: Have you also logged the object you're converting to JSON?

Comment: Also, you are continuing the serialization after the validation fails.

Comment: Also, show us the code for `JSONRepresentation`.  Above you show the code for `JSONRepresentation:`, which is entirely different.

Comment: Yes, what if you call `JSONRepresentation:NO` instead?

Comment: While Hot Licks is undoubtedly right, as an aside, I'd also be inclined to (a) define `result` as a `NSData` (because that's what `dataWithJSONObject` returns); and (b) use `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` rather than than `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[result bytes]]`.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes I logged the NSMutableDictionary and it exists every time. Even converting results from id to NSData does not change anything as well as running JSONRepresentation: set to YES or NO.

Comment: @Rob What did work was your second comment about changing [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[result bytes]] to  [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]. Please add this as an unswer so I can approve it. Thank you

Comment: That is peculiar.  `[result bytes]` is a temp that goes poof when `result` does, but one wouldn't expect that to happen until the method ends.  It sounds like there's a "feature" of ARC that releases `result` immediately after the last reference, which would be before `bytes` is passed to the NSString `init` routine.  It would be interesting to insert a dummy reference to `result` after the string is created and see if that makes the original code behave.

Comment: @HotLicks I didn't suggest `initWithData` for memory semantics, but rather because the `NSData` doesn't include a `NULL` termination character that `stringWithUTF8String` requires. The next byte could, by happenstance, be `NULL`, but you have no assurances of that, AFAIK.

Comment: @Rob - Good point.  If that's the problem then `initWithBytes:length:encoding:` should work.  Though `initWithData` is definitely better.  (However, the lack of null termination shouldn't cause the given symptoms.  Eventually a zero byte would occur in the "garbage", or a storage error would occur.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dataWithJSONObject` method returns a `NSData`, so I'd suggest:

1. To convert a `NSData` into a `NSString`, you should use `initWithData` rather than `stringWithUTF8String`. So, rather than:

   ```
   return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[result bytes]];
   ```

   You should do:

   ```
   return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   ```
2. For the sake of clarity, you probably should define `result` to be a `NSData *` rather than `id`.